# GetPath Remove and Concatenation Char

Tags: c++, string

I will get environment 'APPDATA' and get back to previous directory from APPDATA\Roaming to APPDATA, then I want to concantenate with another directory APPDATA\Local\ finally replace '\' into '\'. Currently I had problem with it. How can I go back directory ?

Codes suppose to be

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 

char* path;
path= getenv("APPDATA"); <!--GetEnv APPDATA-->
??? <!-- Go back directory -->
strncpy(path,"Local\\stuff,12); <!-- add front directory-->
<!-- Replace slash to double slash -->
std::string s = path;
std::replace(s.begin(),s.end(), '\','\\');
```

Comment: Why are you using HTML comments in C++ sourcecode?

Comment: `strncpy()` is a function of the C strings library. In C++ just use `std::string` and its functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the last directory in a string?

If so, you can use std::string::find_last_of( "\\" ) to find the last slash then use the return value to create a substring.  The following example will do that.

```
std::string path = getenv("APPDATA"); //<!--GetEnv APPDATA-->
//??? <!-- Go back directory -->
std::size_t slashPosition = path.find_last_of( "\\" );
// Remove slash at the end if found easier to handle if trailing slash is/not found)
path = path.substr( 0, slashPosition ); 
path += "\\Local\\stuff"; //<!-- add front directory-->
```

I removed the code for replacing the single back with double since it would not work as written and I don't think it was necessary.  I also used a std::string for the path variable to take advantage of methods in std::string.